# Ubuntu freeezes when using GPU

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I've just updated from kernel 3.16 to 3.19.0-30-generic. 
The thing is that this kernel uses CPU graphic card, and this is what I wanted, the problem is that when I suspend Ubuntu it switches to GPU (NVIDIA GTX 850M) and when I turn it on again Ubuntu freezes.
I'm using X.OrgXserver-Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau(open source). But on system details says I'm using Intel® Haswell Mobile.
This also happends when I use a tty.
It always happends when Ubuntu uses de GPU, because my computer has an indicator light that tells you wich graphic card you are using. 
When I suspend or chanche to a tty it becames orange (that means that it is using the GTX 850M) and after that is when it freezes.

My computer is a MSI GE60 2PC:
Intel® Core™ i7-4720HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz × 8 
And I'm using Ubuntu with CairoDock+Gnome effects

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Have you tried with proprietary nvidia driver from hardware drivers and nvidia-prime?

Comment: If the answer below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using very new GPU hardware, it is recommended to use the very latest stable drivers.

Install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers supporting GTX850 from the Proprietary GPU drivers PPA.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

To switch between intel and nvidia graphics - open **NVIDIA X Server Settings** -> **Prime Profiles**.

So when you want to use only the integrated card **switch to intel** - logout and back in - that's it !

Comment: I've installed this and now it works fine! Thanks!